# How can I find the number of identical matrices/data frames in my list

Tags: r, loops, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have a list which contains 100 data frames. I need to find the number of identical dataframes in the list.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  C = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
                  D = c(1, NA, 0, NA))

df2 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  C = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
                  D = c(1, NA, NA, 0))

df3 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  C = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
                  D = c(NA, 1, NA, 0))

df4 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                  B = c(0, 0, 1, 1),
                  C = c(1, 1, 1, 0),
                  D = c(NA, 1, NA, 0))

list1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
list1
```

As you see, `df3` and `df4` in the list are the same. Since the list consists of 4 objects, 6 different comparisons must be made.

Comment: How do you define "number of identical data.frames"? Number of data.frames thare are identical to any other?

Comment: I got your point. Basically, i want to know that I have 100 unique datasets. If i don't, which objects are identical?

Comment: What is your expected output, if say df1, df10, df15 are same and say df2, df50 are same?

Answer (score 5):

#### Pairwise matrix of any duplicated elements

You can use [`outer()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/outer.html) for this:

```r
outer(list1, list1, Vectorize(identical))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Or to get the indices:

```r
outer(list1, list1, Vectorize(identical)) |>
    `diag<-`(FALSE) |>
    which(arr.ind = TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   4   3
# [2,]   3   4
```

#### Indices of any duplicated elements

If you want to know the indices of any duplicated data frames (but not necessarily which elements they are identical to) you can create a small helper function using the base [`duplicated()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) function. Note that `duplicated()` compares each element to the previous element, so the first time an element that appears more than once is seen it is not considered duplicated. The helper function runs from the start and end (`fromLast = TRUE`) so we get the indices of all elements that appear more than once.

```r
which_duplicated  <- function(l) {
    which(duplicated(l) | duplicated(l, fromLast = TRUE))
}
# [1] 3 4
```

#### List of unique data frames

If you just want to a list of the unique data frames you can do:

```r
unique(list1)
# [[1]]
#   A B C  D
# 1 1 0 1  1
# 2 1 0 1 NA
# 3 0 1 1  0
# 4 1 1 0 NA

# [[2]]
#   A B C  D
# 1 1 0 1  1
# 2 1 0 1 NA
# 3 0 1 1 NA
# 4 1 1 0  0

# [[3]]
#   A B C  D
# 1 1 0 1 NA
# 2 1 0 1  1
# 3 0 1 1 NA
# 4 1 1 0  0
```

Comment: `duplicated` is a nice approach, simple and efficient!+1!. But I think it will have an issue if you have 2 or more groups of identical dataframes, e.g., `list1 <- list(df0 = df1, df1, df2, df3, df4)`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks yes I was unclear whether the expected output was the indices of all duplicated data frames, or which data frames they were duplicated with. Not sure if you've seen my edit but it produces a matrix of identifying pairwise duplicates. Your approach is better if the output needs to be a list of groups, though.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to achieve grouping tags, you can simply run `match` + `unique` from base R

```
> match(list1, unique(list1))
[1] 1 2 3 3
```

---

Further more, to distinguish the groups, you can use `split` on top of the output from above, e.g.,

```
grp <- split(seq_along(list1), match(list1, unique(list1)))
```

then filter the group(s) having more than one entries, e.g.,

```
> unname(grp)[lengths(grp) > 1]
[[1]]
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(digest) # We'll use hash strings instead of comparing data.frames

foo <- function(mylist) {
  grps <- split(seq_along(mylist), vapply(mylist, digest, character(1L)))
  list(number_unique = length(grps), identical = unname(grps)[lengths(grps)>1])
}

foo(list1)
# $number_unique
# [1] 3
# 
# $identical
# $identical[[1]]
# [1] 3 4
```

Benchmarking with 100 (small) data.frames

```
list2 <- lapply(1:100, \(i) iris[-sample(1:150, size = 1), ])

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(foo(list2), th1(list2), th2(list2))
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
#  foo(list2)   2.6285   2.7871   5.983731   2.9289   3.4864  92.6672   100
```

Answer (score 3):

`rlang` provides a fast hash, and `collapse` provides fast grouping.

```
library(collapse) # for `qG`
library(rlang) # for `hash`

list1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
qG(vapply(list1, hash, ""), sort = FALSE)
#> [1] 1 2 3 3
#> attr(,"N.groups")
#> [1] 3
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "qG"
```

We can see that there are three unique objects in `list1`, and the third and fourth element are identical (they both belong to group 3).

Benchmarking.

```
library(digest)

list2 <- replicate(1e3, matrix(sample(sample(4, 1)*3), 3), FALSE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  toString = qG(vapply(list2, toString, ""), sort = FALSE),
  digest = qG(vapply(list2, digest, ""), sort = FALSE),
  rlang = qG(vapply(list2, hash, ""), sort = FALSE),
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  toString  8.5588  8.87315  9.597491  9.07445  9.54395 16.9515   100
#>    digest 21.3525 24.49680 29.048084 27.07445 30.48985 88.1293   100
#>     rlang  2.8603  3.09435  5.618076  5.54240  6.53210 15.8621   100
```

Comment: Very nice! Two functions I've never used but definitely will!